# Tomcat maxThread config

Tags: tomcat

I was going through the documentation at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html to understand maxThread and maxConnections. In a BIO setting the default value of maxConnections is same as maxThreads.

What happens if say in one of the requests, the program internally spawns say 30 threads to process a job faster. Does this 30 threads take up the count set by the maxThread? So if maxThread was set to 100, will that reduce it to 70?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internally spawned threads won't take up the maxThreads. The maxThreads only limits the threads which created by tomcat connector.